# Can Facebook pages be indexed by Google's search engine?

Tags: google-search, facebook-pages

We know Facebook pages use iframes. Can these iframes be indexed by search engines for SEO purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook page contents are not seen indexed by Google yet, but the page title and profile information is seen to be tracked, and shown as back links in webmaster tools.

Most of the links inside Facebook pages are carrying the no follow attribute so no linkjuice is seemed to be transferred.

From my observation, how posting links and contents into Facebook page helps is, doing so can make our new content visible so fast to search engine crawlers and the link will be indexed ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they can be - if the search engines chooses to do so.

Comment: Well, it’s Facebook’s choice and not the other way around. Google would _love_ to do it, I’m sure.

Comment: Well it appears that Google is doing so now:   I just googled       "some words I know I posted on the wall of a Facbook page  site:facebook.com        -   and my Facebook page IS listed in the search results.